# how determine the best path that satisfies a condition

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @flat table
(
    id int not null,
    percentage int not null,
    value float not null
)

insert into @flat (id, percentage, value)
select 1,10,0.333
union all
select 1,20,0.4
union all
select 2, 50, 0.5
union all
select 2, 70, 0.67
union all
select 3, 10, 0.125
union all
select 3, 40, 0.325
```

having this sample data, how could i determine the rows that maximize the sum of the values ?
Having the following conditions:

- one percentage per ***id*** only
- the sum of the ***percentages*** must be 100

there is two possible solutions:

```
-- id percentage  value     sum
--  1     10      0.333    0.333  
--  2     50      0.5      0.833 
--  3     40      0.325    1.158

-- id percentage  value     sum
--  1     20      0.4       0.4  
--  2     70      0.67      1.070 
--  3     10      0.125     1.195
```

but it matters only the last one.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i thought i could use something similar like "the coin change" algorithm, where i was retrieving percentages until 0 reached using a recursive cte..no success.

using `code`
select id, 
 (select top 1 percentage from @flat as t2 where t2.id=t1.id order by percentage desc) as percentage
from @flat as t1 group by id

i don't know how to force a running total percentage of 100

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations, you have a [subset sum problem!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum) It's an NP-complete problem. Arriving at the solution is going to call for brute force. i.e. Generate and test all possible subsets. WARNING: This may involve the sketchy Cartesian products your mother warned you about.

Depending on the size of your actual data domain, in SQL that is going to range from "computationally expensive but it works" at best to "who jammed the kernel to 100% and crashed the database server?" at worst.

As a computationally-intensive problem, it is more advisable to solve it in a dynamic programming language than in a SQL DBMS.

Comment: Yes but the specific question has a small "P" value so I guess solving it won't be too intensive.

Comment: That presumes that the P value needed for the real-world problem is accurately represented by poster's example. It may be simplified, as such examples often are. But yes, for OP's sake, hopefully it's a manageable amount of brute force.

Comment: i was able to find the solution using brute force, but its not a generic solution, since i need to add or subtract a "cross apply" to get all the products.